# Bash if -> then if -> else skip to first elif

Tags: bash, shell

Code:

```
if [cond1]
   then if [cond2]
        then ...
        else skip to elif
   fi

elif[cond3]
   then ...
fi
```

If second condition doesn't match skip to elif.

Comment: Sounds like you need a function.

Comment: Somehow escaping this block is bad practice as it would require some sort of go to which, in this case, would begin to lead to some serious spaghetti code.  Write a function, and call it in both places.

Comment: What about `if cond1 && cond2, elif cond3`?

Comment: What are `cond1`, `cond2`, and `cond3`? It will be easier to suggest an appropriate structure if we know the real conditions.

Comment: @chepner Why'd you delete your answer? Unless I'm missing something it just needs a minor tweak (`[ cond3 -o (cond1 -a ! cond2) ]`).

Comment: It was getting a bit repetitive (having to re-evaluate `cond1` and `cond2`). I'd rather know what the real conditions are to determine what is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the below code, `elif quux...` is a placeholder for whatever `elif`s you have after `elif cond3`.

## If you don't need to test `cond3` on skipping

*(That is, you want to execute its code when you skip, even if `cond3` is false.)*

As suggested by @code4me, you could use a function:

```
foo() { 
  # do work
}

if cond1; then
  if cond2; then
    ...
  else
    foo
  fi
elif cond3; then
  foo
elif quux...
```

This is also where @fedorqui's suggestion works:

```
if cond1 && cond2; then
  ...
elif cond3; then
  # do work
elif quux...
```

## If you *do* need to test `cond3` on skipping

The logic gets harder to follow.

```
foo() {
  # Note the condition is tested here now
  if cond3; then
    # do work
  fi
}

if cond1; then
  if cond2; then
    ...
  else
    foo
  fi
else
  # This code is carefully constructed to ensure that subsequent elifs
  # behave correctly
  if ! foo; then
    # Place the other elifs here
    if quux...
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's your code:

```
if [cond1]
then
    if [cond2]
    then
        doX
    else
        skip to elif
    fi
    doY
elif[cond3]
then
    doZ
fi
```

I've added `doX`, `doY`, and `doZ` as placeholders for whatever code you'll be running in those cases.  So, this means that:

- `doX` is executed when `[cond1]` is true and `[cond2]` is true
- `doY` is executed when `[cond1]` is true and `[cond2]` is true
- `doZ` is executed when either:

  - `[cond1]` is true and `[cond2]` is false and `[cond3]` is true
  - `[cond1]` is false and `[cond3]` is true

This means that your code can be written like this instead:

```
if [cond1] && [cond2]
then
    doX
    doY
elif [cond3]
    doZ
fi
```

Edit: it looks like @fedorqui actually suggested this in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what that `elif` is doing that you want your code to execute it in the middle of the first `if` section. Is that `elif` part something that needs to be a function?

Otherwise, you could recode your `if` statement to take `condition2` into account.

```
if [ condition1 -a ! condition2 ]
then
    ....
elif [ condition3 -o condition1 ]
    ....
fi
```

Now, the `if` clause will only execute if both *condition1* is true **and** *condition2* is not true. No need to check *condition2* inside of the else clause.

In your `elif` clause, you will execute if **either** *condition3* is true **or** *condition1* is true. By default, this will execute if *condition1* is true only if *condition2* is also true. Otherwise, you would have executed the `if` clause.

By the way, some of the answers ***almost*** match what I gave. However, they need to add the `or` clause to that `elif` condition. What if *condition1* is true, *condition2* is true, but *condition3* is false? You want to execute that `elif` clause. Right?